# Not able to fetch data from VSTS through REST using java.....always getting a connect time out error

Tags: java, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to connect VSTS through REST in JAVA but always getting connect time out. Using this code I'm able to connect with http but always getting error when trying to connect with https. Will be posting the error in comments. Getting this error -> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

```
  public class RESTInvoker {

  public static class ConnectionFactory implements HttpURLConnectionFactory 
{

    SSLContext sslContext;

    public ConnectionFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url) throws 
   IOException {
        initializeProxy();
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            System.out.println("The valus is....");
            HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) 
   url.openConnection();
            httpsCon.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());


     httpsCon.setSSLSocketFactory(getSslContext().getSocketFactory());
            return httpsCon;
        } else {
            return con;
        }

    }

    public SSLContext getSslContext() {
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new 
   SecureTrustManager() }, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            //

 Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
  ex);
        } catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
            //

 Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
 ex);
        }
        return sslContext;
    }

    private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
        return new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession 
 sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String username = "xxx";
        String token = "xxx";
        String tfsurl = "xxx";
        String collectionName = "xxx";
        String prjName = "xxxx";

        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(token.getBytes());
        System.out.println(encodedBytes);

        String ab = "https://" + username + ":" + encodedBytes + "@" + 
tfsurl
                + "/Inforce%20Portal/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=4.0";

        // Client client =Client.create();
        System.out.println(ab);

        try {
            String input = "{\"query\":\"Select [System.Id], [System.Title], 
  [System.State] From WorkItems\"}";

            URLConnectionClientHandler cc = new 
  URLConnectionClientHandler(new ConnectionFactory());
            Client client = new Client(cc);

            WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://" + username + ":" + token + "@" + tfsurl + "/"
                    + prjName + "/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=4.0");

            ClientResponse response = null;

    response=webResource.type("application/json").accept("application/json").post(ClientResp 
 onse.class,
                    input);

            String data = "";

            try {
                data = response.getEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println(data);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class SecureTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) 
    throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) 
   throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }

        public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0) {
            return true;
        }

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that it is not related to your code.

I recommend that you could check the TFS server whether there is a Https binding.

[image]

If there is no Https bindings, please have a try to add the corrosponding Https binds

[image]

Comment: Editing or changing the binding is not in my access. Is there any other way in which I can make a connection to fetch data from VSTS through REST using JAVA

Comment: According to your code, it seems that you use the TFS instead of Azure Devops(VSTS). The first thing is that you need to make sure that https is supported by your TFS server. If not, I think there is no other way to do that.

Comment: ok... so can you give me sample code to connect with VSTS as I'm unable to make any progress on this and it would be very helpful if you can help me on this